# How to create a python class with list variable

Tags: python, class

How to write a class that makes
an list for each instance. I am
concerned on the class part.
I know how to make a int , double
or string, but I need an list
(string).

The list will have later values
assigned to it, when it is an
instance and there will be
custom methods in the class
for the objects/instances.

Comment: Just add a variable `self.my_list = []` or `my_list = lsit()` in your `__init__()` method?

Comment: The second way should be `self.my_list = list()` of course. I obviously failed my proof reading. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Classes in Python can have their member variables instantiated within the `__init__` function, which is called upon creation of the class object. You should [read up on classes here](http://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html) if you are unfamiliar with how to create one. Here is an example class that instantiates a list as a member and allows appending to the list:

```
   class ListContainer:
       def __init__(self):
          self.internal_list = [] # list member variable, unique to each instantiated class
       def append(elem):
          self.internal_list.append(elem)
       def getList():
          return self.internal_list

  list_container_1 = ListContainer()
  list_container_1.append('example')
  print list_container_1.getList() # prints ['example']
  list_container_2 = ListContainer()
  print list_container_2.getList() # prints []
```